# Python modules no longer available after updating python

Tags: python, module, pip

I had a few modules installed with pip in my Python 3.8 version. However I installed the 3.9.7 version and now I'm not able to use the modules I had installed in the 3.8 version.

Is there any way to use the modules I already have installed for the 3.8 version in the 3.9 or I'll need to install everything again?

Note: I'm using MacOS Big Sur.

Comment: How did you install the various versions of Python? How did you install the distributions into the 3.8 version? Did you use virtual environments?

Comment: The 3.8 version I think I installed through the developer tool, I installed it in the first day that I started using MacOS through the terminal. Now I installed the 3.9 version downloading it from python.org since I wasn't finding a way to auto update the 3.8 version i have. I guess that's why it is installed in different places and it isn't able to get the modules already installed in the older version.

Comment: That's right, the new version won't have access to the old version's modules. So you need to install all packages that you want also into the new version (using the same method as you did for the old one). If you were using [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), you could upgrade the version of Python via `conda install python=3.9` and it would upgrade all other installed packages as needed.

Comment: Yeah, I guess there's no other option. But now if I install the next python version from python.org will it be able to get the modules I install in this new version (3.9.7 also installed from python.org) ?

Comment: Do you mean if you install the next micro version? I.e. `3.9.x`? That should work. However for minor version upgrades (i.e. `3.x.0`) it won't work, because they have their own site package directories. That's intended because minor version upgrades might introduce incompatibilities in the compiled bytecode.

Comment: So every time it has a version upgrade to 3.x or even the 4.x I will need to install the modules again?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But it's not a big deal. You can use `python3.8 -m pip freeze > env.txt` in order to export the currently installed distributions together with their version numbers and then use `python3.9 -m pip install -r env.txt` to install the exact same packages into the new version of Python. Minor version upgrades are released once per year and chances are that 4.x will never come, so that's a moderate amount of work to be done.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment.
Should I be worried about gathering a lot of modules in different versions or it isn't such a big thing?

Comment: That's the normal way, typically you'd even work with [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) which sandbox your package installations *within* a certain version of Python, in order to prevent conflicts between different projects (e.g. you're developing two projects A and B on Python 3.9.7, and A needs `foopkg==1.2` while B needs `foopkg>=1.3`).